# How to clear the /dev/kmsg ring buffer?

Tags: linux, kernel, logs, buffer

Is there a way for me to force clear the /dev/kmsg kernel ring buffer?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

Yes:

```
sudo dmesg -C
```

See [`man dmesg`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html) for details.

Comment: Unfourtenatly that does not delete the `/dev/kmsg` logs.. I still see those using the following procedure:
1. sudo dmesg -C
2. Run :

```
with open('/dev/kmsg', 'rb') as file:
    while True:
        message = file.readline()
        print(message.decode(errors='ignore').strip())
```

Comment: What do you mean "delete"? Do you want to put 0 to the content? The above command reset the ring buffer, so the content will be interpreted as empty. But it is a ring buffer, and there data will not be overridden with zero. (also in this case, for good reasons). If you have a sound user case, you may issue a feature request. But it should be solid, else why to make code much more complex and with possible bugs for no good reasons?